# How to Show Half Event Width on Start date and End date in FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I am working on a hotel management system and want to show bookings against every room on full calendar monthly view.

Now suppose, we have a booking from November 1, 2020 to November 7, 2020. In this case, the event start date will be November 1, 2020 and end date will be November 7, 2020. As full calendar shows the events inclusive of start date and exclusive of end date, the event will be shown from November 1, 2020 to November 6, 2020.

What I want to show (in monthly view and resource timeline monthly view) is:

Half width of event on start date (to highlight it as check in date)
Half width of event on end date (to highlight it as check out date)

Is there a way to achieve this currently?

Comment: You could really only achieve this with the timeline view I think, the month view takes no account of partial days, or times of day when it renders the events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reference to [this](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5933), we can add the following css

```
.fc-event-start {
    margin-left: 65px !important;
}
.fc-event-end {
    margin-right: 65px !important;
}
```